# Multiple sensors = multiple deep learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, iot

Let's say I have 30,000 vibration sensors monitoring 30,000 drills (1 sensor per drill) in different workplaces. I need to detect anomalies in vibration patterns.
Given we have enough historical data, how would you go about creating models for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat ambiguous question, however you can follow the following broad steps to perform anomaly detection:

1. **Load the data** into your computing environment, maybe Python, MATLAB, or R. This is assuming your data can fit into memory, else you may want to consider setting up an Hadoop or Spark cluster on Amazon EC2 or other virtual clusters.
2. You should perform some **EDA** to understand your data better. This will reveal more on the underlying struture of the data, what kind of distribution is it from, etc.
3. Make rough **visual plots** of your data if possible. This will come in handy when you need to polish some final plots for a presentation when reporting your analysis.
4. Based on the EDA, you can then intuitivey prepare your data for processing. You may need to **transform, rescale or standardize the dataset** before applying any *Machine Learning* technique for Anomaly detection.
5. For **supervised datasets** (i.e. labels are provided), you may consider algorithms such as SVM, Neural Networks, XGBoost or any other appropriate supervised technique. *However, great care much be taken in evaluating the results because typical to anomaly detection datasets*, there is more often than not a very small number of positive examples (y = 1) with respect to the total number of examples. This is called **class imbalance**. There are various ways of mitigating this problem. See [Class Imbalance Problem](http://www.chioka.in/class-imbalance-problem/).
6. For **unsupervised datasets**, techniques such as the density based methods (i.e. Local Outlier Factor (LOF) and its varieties, k-Nearest Neighbor (kNN) -> its a very popular method), One-class SVM, etc. A monograph of unsupervised methods for anomaly detection is detailed in this study. [A Comparative Evaluation of Unsupervised Anomaly Detection Algorithms for Multivariate Data](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0152173#sec008)

**N.b.**.
 - Don't forget to consider rudimentary ML practices when building your models such as: splitting into training set/ test set or exploring resampling methods such as k-fold CV, LOOCV, etc to control bias/ variance in your results.
 - Explore other techniques such as Ensemble methods (i.e. Boosting & Bagging algorithms) to improde model accuracy.
 - Deep learning techniques such as the **Muli-layer Perceptron** can be explored on this problem. If there is some time-series component, a **Recurrent Neural Network, RNN** can be explored.